# Can you use spatial regression models to analyse survey data with a binary outcome?

Tags: logistic, autocorrelation, binary-data, survey, spatial

I have a survey of about 2700 respondents distributed across 35 municipalities in the Netherlands, and I am modelling a binary outcome (voting for a political party) as a function of detailed geographical data. I want to account for spatial autocorrelation in the data and have access to the geocoded addresses of respondents. So far, I used multilevel logistic regression with respondents nested in municipalities, but I was wondering whether it is possible to use a spatial error or spatial lag model instead. As far as I can see, there are two issues here:

1: Most spatial models model a linear outcome, is it possible to extend this to a binary outcome? How would this work? I can imagine you could model the likelihood of an outcome occuring based on the likelihood of it occuring among a respondent's neighbours (based on some sort of spatial weights matrix) but am unsure how this would go in practice.
2: Is it correct to use spatial models to analyze survey data? This might pose a problem because I don't have information on the full population but rather on some randomly selected individuals.